# How Can User Be A Distribution List?

Tags: active-directory

I sent an email to a distribution list in Outlook but when I tried to look at the members it was empty.

On further inspection it appears to be a person:

```
objectClass = top;person;organizationalPerson;user
```

Whereas 'normal' lists are groups (`objectClass = top;group`) with a list of `member`.

How does this using a `person` object work as a group/distribution list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` and `msExchRecipientDisplayType` attributes on the user account. They control how the object shows up in the GAL. It's technically possible to set those fields such that the user shows up as a DL in the GAL.

See [here for a reference](http://www.mistercloudtech.com/2016/05/18/reference-to-msexchrecipientdisplaytype-msexchrecipienttypedetails-and-msexchremoterecipienttype-values/). e.g.

```
msExchRecipientDisplayType = 1 (0x1) = Distribution Group
msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 1073741824 = Role Group
```